# How to set rules to none in p:panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Unlike `<h:panelGrid>`, `<p:panelGrid>` has no option like `rules`. All rules appear between cells in `<p:panelGrid>`, by default. For example,

```
<p:panelGrid style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="3">
                <h:outputText value="Header"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>1</p:column>
        <p:column>2</p:column>
        <p:column>3</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>1</p:column>
        <p:column>2</p:column>
        <p:column>3</p:column>
    </p:row>

</p:panelGrid>
```

will display a grid layout as follows.

[image: Grid Layout]

How to remove these lines (horizontal & vertical) between cells something like an HTML table `<table rules="none">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS

```css
.ui-panelgrid tr,.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
   border: none;       
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to apply this CSS classes only to particular `<p:dataGrid>`s on the page? It is applied to all `<p:panelGrid>`s on the page.

Comment: Just give your panelGrid a styleClass, let's say myPanelGridStyle, then append it to .ui-panelgrid... In that case it would be .myPanelGridStyle.ui-panelgrid ... On both of the css selectors